# snprintf() , overflow possibility?

Tags: c, printf

I have fixed size arrays - arr1 and arr2.

```
char arr1[100];
char arr2[100];
snprintf(arr2, sizeof(arr2), "%sAND", "CONTENTOFARRAY2");
snprintf(arr1, sizeof(arr1), "%sAND", arr2);
```

Will the second snprintf , cause a buffer overflow ? I have tried some testing and no issues were noticed so far.

Has anyone noticed any such issues?

Comment: "Will the second snprintf , cause a buffer overflow ?" -- why would it? The string you are putting is shorter than 100 chars, and `snprintf` is guaranteed to not overflow anyway.

Comment: As long as the correct/valid destination, size and valid arguments are used, buffer overflow is not possible.

Comment: That's the whole point of `snprintf`, given the correct size (and you've passed the correct size), `sprintf` guarantees not to write more than `size-1` elements and '\0'-terminate the string.

Comment: Sorry for sounding so naive , but won't the second snprintf will try to copy arr2 ( size 100 ) + "AND" . So it would be longer than the destination which has a length of 100.

Comment: @chux. Thanks for the answer , that was the real concern.

Comment: The second argument to `snprintf` is the maximum number number of bytes it will copy. You've specified `sizeof(arr1)` in the first call, and `sizeof(arr2)` in the second. It's that simple. (Truncation can be a concern, and there are cases where that can be really bad if you don't deal with it properly.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 2nd call, `"%s"` does not direct `snprintf()` to use all of `arr2[100]` - see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143467/snprintf-overflow-possibility/49143661#comment85292406_49143467), just the first part of it that constitutes a string - which hopeful is not excessive.

Had `arr2[]` been populated with a longer string - say 98 characters, `arr1[]` would receive a truncated version of the concatenation. Still no buffer overflow.

---

As `snprintf()` is design to guard against *overflow*, *overflow* does not need to be checked.  Instead, prudent use of `snprintf()` checks the result for *truncation*.

> The `snprintf` function returns the number of characters that would have been written had `n` been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative  value if an encoding error occurred. C11dr §7.21.6.3 3

```
int count = snprintf(arr1, sizeof arr1, "%sAND", arr2);
if (count < 0 || count >= sizeof arr1) Handle_Error();
```